# Split not working in IE8 but working in FF and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I want to split following string.

```
Ex: "Good Site" www.test.com
```

I want to store as

```
anchor text = Good Site
href = www.test.com
```

I tried below regex to split, but it is not working in IE. It is working in FF and Chrome.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

    <p id="demo">Click the button to display the array values after the split.</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<script>
    function myFunction()
   {
     var str = '"How are you doing today?" I am good';
     var res = str.split(/"(.*?)"/);
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
   }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: .split() creates array. and you are assigning array to innerHTML?

Comment: @RohitAwasthi That will just turn the array into comma separated string, it should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE (Safari too iirc) doesn't include the captured patterns in the resulting array when using `.split()`. that said, you should use matching instead of splitting:

```
>> '"Good Site" www.test.com'.match(/^"([^"]+)"\s*(.*)/);

[""Good Site" www.test.com", "Good Site", "www.test.com"]
```

Comment: The Question was about ie8 vs other

Comment: I tested his code in ie8 vs chrome : difference results. that's his question actually.

Comment: I'm not surprised; still, one should use the right tool for the job at hand and `.split()` is known to have some quirks on IE when it comes to capturing patterns.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
myFunction() {
   var str = '"Good Site" www.test.com';
   var res = str.split('"').splice(1); // outputs: Good Site, www.test.com
   var anchor = res[0]; // Good Site
   var href = res[1]; // www.test.com
   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
```

---

When this code executes only with `split()` like this `var res = str.split('"');` then the output gets something like this:

```
,Good Site, www.test.com
```

and its length is `3` which is not required, This is due to split by `'"'` inverted comma so length is `3`, so here we have to do `.splice(1)` to remove the empty index in the array.

```
var res = str.split('"').splice(1);
```

so output of it and length is `2`:

```
Good Site, www.test.com
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2hDjF/)